# How to set Zoom In and Zoom out in Google ios sdk map using Button

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working with GoogleMaps First Time and Want to know how Should I implement a Zoom In and Zoom out on GoogleMap with the help of +/- button...
I had set The GmsCameraPosition but not clear about how to zoom in and Out Using Button...
I had To button and on there Action I'm using like below

```
-(void)zoomOutMapView:(id)sender
{

    for (CGFloat i= 10; i<=15; i++) {
        [mapView animateToZoom:i ];
        [mapView setMinZoom:10 maxZoom:15];
    }
}

-(void)zoomInMapView:(id)sender
{
    for (CGFloat i= 10; i<=15; i--)
    {
        [mapView animateToZoom:i ];
        [mapView setMinZoom:10 maxZoom:15];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create one common method for zoom In/Out the `GmsCameraPosition` and create the one common `CGFloat` in your viewcontroller.

for example

on your `ViewDidLoad`

```
CGFloat currentZoom = 10.0f;
```

create the common method like

```
-(Void)ZoominOutMap:(CGFloat)level
{
camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
                                 longitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude
                                      zoom:level];
self.MapView.camera = camera;
}
```

if you press the `+` Button call like

```
-(void)zoomInMapView:(id)sender
{
 currentZoom = currentZoom + 1;

 [self ZoominOutMap:currentZoom];
}
```

if you press the `-` Button call like

```
-(void) zoomOutMapView:(id)sender
{
 currentZoom = currentZoom - 1;

 [self ZoominOutMap:currentZoom];
}
```

Comment: I had currently USed     GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:22.7          longitude:75.8 zoom:10]; like this so my zoom level is 10 can I zoom in From level 10 inside my button method and zoom out too

Comment: ThanQ so so so Much YOu saved My night This is Working Like a charm ...100% for this Anbu.Karthik Thanks frnd Can You Give me Ur Email Id

Comment: ya tanx a lot bro... if my answer is fine give the upvote for the answer, and my mail id is karthik.saral@gmail.com (FB,Twitter, SO, GMail, Skype, GitHub)

Answer (score 0):

We have GMSCameraPosition : class that aggregates all camera position parameters

sample usage:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.8683
                                                        longitude:151.2086
                                                             zoom:6];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView_.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite;
```

we can use this camera object to set zoom level

```
camera.zoom = 6;
```

also we can re-assign camera again to map
try out :)

Comment: I had Done It alredy But my question is I want to achieve varaible zoom In/Zoom Out On button

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple way to #ZoomInZoomOut byClicking on button in #iOS #GoogleMap #Swift

step1 : take command variable to manage zoom just like bellow

```
var currentZoom : Float = 10.0
```

step2 : change value of variable inside method/action of buttons

```
@IBAction func zoomIn(sender : UIButton)
{
    self.currentZoom = self.currentZoom + 1
    
}
@IBAction func zoomOut(sender : UIButton)
{
    self.currentZoom = self.currentZoom - 1
}

// you can also directly write mapView.animate method inside above IBAction 
func zoomInZoomOutGoogleMap() {
    mapView.animate(toZoom: currentZoom)
}
```