# How to zoom in/out GoogleMap using button

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am trying to Zoom In and Zoom Out a map by using two button on map.
i am follow this way but not get proper solution-

My code is -

```
var currentZoom:Float = 10
```

.

```
func zoomInOut(level:Float)  {
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(26.6139, longitude: 77.2090, zoom: level)

    self.customMapView.camera = camera
}

@IBAction func zoomPlus(sender: AnyObject) {

    currentZoom = currentZoom + 1;
    print("Plus")

    self.customMapView.animateToZoom(currentZoom)
}


@IBAction func zoomMinus(sender: AnyObject) {

    currentZoom = currentZoom - 1;
    print("Minus")

    self.customMapView.animateToZoom(currentZoom)
}
```

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901061/how-to-set-zoom-in-and-zoom-out-in-google-ios-sdk-map-using-button) if it can help you or give you an idea about your problem.

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value      ->  self.customMapView.animateToZoom(currentZoom)

Comment: getting error in above edited code

Answer (score 0):

Use zoomTo `float` type parameter in your method and increase/decrease it with Your button action and call as you required.

```
func ZoomMap(zoomTo: Float){
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(26.6139,longitude:77.2090, zoom:zoomTo)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 667), camera:camera)
    }
```

Comment: can you elaborate more, i am new to Google Map

Comment: i am call this func in my button action but . nothing happen

Comment: Simply, ""mapView.animateToZoom(Yourvalue)"" is worked for my case simply decrease/increase YourValue in button action.

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: self.customMapView.animateToZoom(currentZoom)